# Can I set primary of display for validator?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Question from title.

Example:

One field has two validator: compareValidator and rangeValidator. CompareValidator checks if field has integer type. RangeValidator checks if field has greater then 18 and less then 120. But If I write random letters, both of error message are displayed. Logically, that only message error from CompareValidator would be displayed.

Do you have any proposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RangeValidator can be set to check for type too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type.aspx. Set it to Integer and then you won't need the second validator anymore.

The error message could be like: **The value should be a number between 18 and 120**.

Comment: It is great oportunity, but it cannot sound like, that, my both message are so diffrent. Comparator message is short, only about format. Range message is long and this is a condition associated with age.

Comment: Though the range message is somewhat longer it's more consistent and provides the intent of the message. Having multiple messages, except a required field, mostly reduces clarity.